# Як відповісти на фразеологізм "Ні пуху, ні пера"?

Tags: фразеологізми

В українській мові є фразеологізм "[Ні пуху ні пера](http://getword.ru/ukr/slovari.php?word=%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0&submit=submit&table=uk_fraz)", так само як і в російській мові є "ни пуха ни пера". Однак, якщо росіяни зазвичай відповідають на цей фразеологізм "к чёрту", то як це роблять українці?

Серед відомих мені словників ([словник Савченко](http://univer.nuczu.edu.ua/tmp_metod/1047/%D1%E0%E2%F7%E5%ED%EA%EE%20%CB.%20%C3._%D0%EE%F1%B3%E9%F1%FC%EA%EE-%F3%EA%F0%E0%BF%ED%F1%FC%EA%E8%E9%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%ED%E8%EA%20%F1%EB%EE%E2%EE%F1%EF%EE%EB%F3%F7%E5%ED%FC.%20%D2%F0%F3%E4%ED%EE%F9%B3%20%EF%E5%F0%E5%EA%EB%E0%E4%F3.pdf), [Російсько-український](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile2.php?transfer=folders/pe/puh.html), вже наведений вище Фразеологічний словник) є приклад вживання цього фразеологізму, але немає прикладу відповіді на нього.

Знайшов на сайті "Тут цікаво" статтю, де пише, що традиційною відповіддю є "**(Пішов) До біса!**". Однак сама стаття є перекладом з російської. А на цьому сайті, який швидше за все є також перекладом (бо здається, він вже раніше з'являвся в коментарях до якогось мого питання) знайшов ще такі варіанти як:

**"Ні чорта, ні диявола"**

**"Іди під три чорти! Сама курка общипана або півень обдертий"**

**"З Богом!"**

**"Ні риби, ні луски!"** (справді, є і такий вислів, але його кажуть [риболовам](https://uain.press/language/v-yacheslav-vasylchenko-mova-pobazhajte-reshti-chogo-hochete-sobi-631257), тому він не може бути відповіддю)

Цікаво, чи є якісь норми, чи на це побажання можна відповісти як завгодно? Чи, можливо, взагалі можна не відповдіти?

Гадаю, що наведені мною приклади у питанні взяті з дуже ненанадійних джерел, однак, мені не вдалося знайти прикладу вживання цього фразеологізму і відповіді до нього в літературних творах. Буду також вдячний за такі приклади.

Answer (score 4):

В українській мові немає крилатого виразу «ни пуха, ни пера». Це калька з російської. Відповідної одіоми немає, тому перекладають так: «ні цвяха, ні жезла», «ні пушинки, ні шерстинки» чи « ні хвоста, ні луски». Зазвичай відповідають - «до біса!».

Comment: Дуже цікава версія й приклади. Лиш одну річ маю сказати: на цьому сайті не заохочуються відповіді без підкріплення джерелами (посилань на поважні словники, книги, авторів тощо). Не могли б ви додати такі джерела до своєї відповіді? Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour](https://goo.gl/XbjRge), [How to Ask](https://goo.gl/KuCfff) а також [«Якими мають бути гарні запитання і відповіді»](https://goo.gl/wnuKFr). Щоб виправити відповідь, натисніть кнопку edit.

Comment: Будь ласка, надайте джерела до інформації, викладеної у відповіді. Неправильно: *«тому перекладають так»* — бо незрозуміло, хто перекладає. Може, то бомж якийсь неписьменний. :-) Правильно: *«дохтур філології Такий-то пропонує перекладати так, підручник такий-то, виданий Міністерством освіти, пропонує сяк, а словник Інституту Лінгвістики імені Макса Фасмера перекладає ось так»*. Наразі кількість корисної інформації у запитанні значно більша, аніж у вашій відповіді, а має бути навпаки.

Comment: Іще *ні луски ні зябри*

Comment: Українською відповіддю буде: Засць!

Answer (score 3):

В СУМ-11 стаття слова ["перо"](http://sum.in.ua/s/pero) містить фразеологізм ***"ні пуха, ні пера"***

> ***Ні пуху ні пера***: а) ***традиційна формула побажання успіху, удачі на
>   полюванні***. Привітання, обійми міцні, Побажання мисливські чудні:
>   Цей — ні пуху! А той — ні пера! (Платон Воронько, Мирний неспокій,
>   1960, 131); б) ***взагалі побажання успіху, звичайно жартівливе (на
>   іспитах і т. ін.)***. — Понаймалися, кажете, — заговорив Баклагов.. — Що
>   ж... ні пуху вам, ні пера (Олесь Гончар, Таврія, 1952, 111).

Уривок з ["Таврія"](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=3131&page=14) О. Гончар

> — До Фальцфейнів,— відповів Валерик,—в Асканію.
>
> — Що ж... ні пуху вам, ні пера. До речі, там приятель мій садівникує.
>   Мурашко Іван Тимофійович. Зустрінеш — кланяйся.
>
> — Дякую,— сказав Валерик і задумався. Вони знову помовчали, проте їхня
>   мовчанка була якоюсь природною, не обтяжливою ні для кого і навіть
>   ніби зближувала всіх трьох.

З цього діалогу, можна зробити вмсновок, що відповідь - "дякую".

Приклад з першого значення наведений в СУМ, на жаль не знайшла.

Окрім того Фразеологічний словник української мови мість такий вираз, як ***["до біса"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53393/356095.html)***

> до бі́са. 1. кого, чого і без додатка. 3. Уживається для вираження
>   категоричного небажання мати справу з ким-, чим-небудь, терпіти
>   когось, щось.

Отже, наведена вами стаття з сайту ["Тут цікаво"](http://tut-cikavo.com/krylati-frazy/245-chomu-bazhayut-ni-pukhu-ni-pera) подає цілком правдиву інформацію. Тому, я вважаю, що відповіддю на фразеологізм ***"ні пуха, ні пера"*** може бути вираз ***"до біса"***.

Answer (score -2):

Думаю, правильніше вживати питомо українське: **Ні пера ні пуху!** Як це робив майстер слова славетний Остап Вишня. Посилання на джерело: http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine6-13.pdf

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Зверніть увагу, запитання стосується того, якою має бути **відповідь** на це побажання. Ваше уточнення стосовно форми самого побажання може бути зноскою до відповіді, яка *відповідає* на запитання, але не може бути самостійною відповіддю. Щоб відредагувати допис, натисніть [edit]. Сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/) надають більше інформації.

Comment: Хочу трішки додати до попереднього коментаря: ви насправді можете поставити своє питання. Наприклад: "чи є вислів "ні пуху, ні пера" питомим для української мови?" й навести свої міркування із посиланнями на джерела. І спільнота спробує розібратися.

Answer (score -2):

Найправильніше буде вживати [з роси і води](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/z-rosu-ta-z-vodu).

Comment: споріднене, але не те, що тут треба.

Comment: Недостатньо аргументована відповідь.